# jquery ending string at space

Tags: jquery, variables, whitespace

I have a form to 'create a tag'. Using the jQuery code below.

```
$("#createtag").submit(function() { //same as above, but for form submit instead of button click
   var newtag     = $('#newtag').attr('value');
   var type_id     = $('#type_id').attr('value'); 
   var company_id     = $('#company_id').attr('value'); 
         $('#createtag').load("../contacts/action_createtag.php?newtag="+ newtag + "&type_id=" + type_id + "&company_id=" + company_id).append('#createtags');
   return false;
  });
```

But i have just realised, if the 'newtag' variable includes a space, thats where it will end. Watching it through firebug, if theres no space the parameters appear like this:

```
company_id 5495
newtag test
type_id 2
```

But when a space is entered, it appears like this:

```
newtag test
```

Does anybody know why this could be happening? Why it is not passing the proper variables to the loaded page?

Thanks in advance!

Ryan

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use [`encodeURIComponent()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Global_Functions/encodeURIComponent) on the values:

```
$('#createtag').load("../contacts/action_createtag.php?newtag="+
  encodeURIComponent(newtag) + "&type_id=" + encodeURIComponent(type_id) +
  "&company_id=" + encodeURIComponent(company_id)).append('#createtags');
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to encode your variables.

Use [`encodeURIComponent()`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_encodeURIComponent.asp)

Answer (score 1):

I think you must encode your space as a `%20` in the URL because if you pass it as a space it will mark the end of the URL. I don't think that jQuery load does any kind of special character escaping by itself.

Comment: the space is the problem in this example, but what if someone put an ampersand in the field?

Answer (score 1):

Encode your newtag value with encodeURI()

```
$('#createtag').load("../contacts/action_createtag.php?newtag="+ encodeURI(newtag) + "&type_id=" + encodeURI(type_id) + "&company_id=" + encodeURI(company_id)).append('#createtags');
```